# CSS two transitions on one element (:hover and :hover:after) not working

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm recently trying to apply two CSS transitions two one element, one of them onto the element itself and the other one onto its :after. As of now the only working animation/transition is the :after one. And this is my code:

```
#menu {
height: 40px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
margin-left: 660px;
padding-left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 600px;
}

#menu li {
color: black;
display: inline;
font-size: 25px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
transition: color .2s; /*not working*/
width: 150px;
}

#menu li:hover {
color: white;
}

#menu li:after {
background-color: black;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 0px;
margin-top: -40px;
position: absolute;
transition: height .2s; /*working*/
width: 150px;
}

#menu li:hover:after {
height: 40px;
}
```

My problem is the transition from the element itself is not working.
Is there any solution for this issue?

Appreciating your answers!

Comment: please do in fiddle?

Comment: color has a transition?

Comment: Its working the thing is background color and font color both are same due to which the effect is not noticed and also the :after is overlapping the text. Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvAwx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Tushar's comment, it is working but the `:after` pseudo-element is covering the `<li>` (that is, `:after` is rendered above the `<li>`).

Removing `position:absolute` from the pseudo-element fixes the problem - see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pnuLo06/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably stupid but try adding -moz-,-webkit- or -o- to your css

Comment: No it's not depending on what browser you test, but in his case it works in one case and not in another with same syntax

Comment: @AlexDom yeah i never thought about that